# C structure struct pointer and functions

Tags: c, struct

I have recently read a code but I have a doubt in code

```
toTs *now = try();
now->index = 30;
```

Where `toTs is a struct` and `try()` is a function with return type `toTs*`

`*now` being a pointer can keep address of label `try()` but as `try()` not being a structure variable `now` can't access it like struct and can never access it like `now->index=30`.

After compiling it shows segmentation fault.
I just want to ask is above code legitimate or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct toT {
    int index;
} toTs;

toTs lst[3];

toTs *try() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        toTs *current = &lst[i];
        printf("%d\n", current->index);
        if (current->index == 3) {
            printf("test work");
            return current;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        lst[i].index = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("test %d\n", lst[i].index);
    }

    toTs *now = try();
    now->index = 30;

    printf("current %d\n", now->index);
    printf("current %d\n", lst[2].index);
}
```

now is a struct pointer that can point to struct variable but try() is not a struct variable nor array of data structure its a function

Comment: Where's the definition of `toTs` & `try()`?

Comment: `try` is not a keyword/reserved-word in C, so no conflict there. You need to allocate memory for `now` inside `try()` or before calling `try()`.

Comment: Sorry i think i was not able to make you understand what  i wanted to tell

Comment: Share the full definition of `try()` function code.

Comment: ok @SparKot ,thanks for giving time for my doubts

Comment: Where is the declaration of `lst[]`, a global variable. Where is it populated with values.

Comment: In the `try()` what will you return when `lst[]` doesn't have index-value `3`? Compiler should issue warnings for this code.

Comment: Because `lst[]` has values only `0, 1, 2`; `lst[]` is array of structures, if `try()` returns address of `lst[]` member then `toTs *now = try();` is valid.

Comment: Compiler not raised an error but i know there something should be returned when list[] is not 3. But my question is how 'now = try();
now->index = 30;' this is possible. try() is function with codes not a empty address space or struct variable which can be done through 'now->index'.This part raises my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always return a valid `toTs*` from `try()` for the code to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct toT {
    int index;
} toTs;

toTs lst[4];

toTs *try() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        toTs *current = &lst[i];
        printf("%d\n", current->index);
        if (current->index == 3) {
            printf("test work");
            return current;
        }
    }
    return &lst[3]; // return a spare structure.
}

int main() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        lst[i].index = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("test %d\n", lst[i].index);
    }

    toTs *now = try();
    now->index = 30;

    printf("current %d\n", now->index);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Final %d\n", lst[i].index);
    }
}
```

You're confusing function pointers with plain pointers in C. Function pointers go deeper : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer

Answer (score 0):

This code is not particularly healthy.

Given the way `lst` is initialized, when you call `try()` it will reach the end of that function without a return statement.

The C Standard says that if you use the return value of a function, without actually returning a value, that's undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry if i have wasted your time but please forget everything about code and just tell me how this is possible "toTs *now = try();
now->index = 30;" a struct pointer pointing to a function and than writing "now->index=30" there isn't it accessing area of code

Comment: Struct pointer is not pointing to a function. A function is returning a struct pointer to save in a struct pointer variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was my issue @SparKot and you solved it.